# Spring JPA with a database that doesn't have Foreign Keys

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, jpa

I have to rewrite an old software in Spring Boot. This software has a database which doesn't have any FK. My problem is that I can't map a Class to JPA if it has objects from other classes that arent related with one of JPA annotations for FKs.

Do you know if it's possible to make JPA ignore or disable the FK constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Whether your database has foreign keys or not, it doesn't matter at all to Hibernate. Hibernate doesn't check your database for foreign keys. Of course you may have some problems on the database side, but Hibernate will just map queries according to your entity classes, not the foreign keys in database.

If you want Hibernate to create your database schema on application startup and you want it to be as close as possible to the real one (for testing let's say) you can use this annotation to tell Hibernate to not create foreign keys:

```html
@JoinColumn(name = "SOME_ID", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
```

Comment: Do I still need to use for example @OneToMany notation?

Comment: If you want the relationship on code level then yes, how else would Hibernate know to map the relations?